# Getting i is undefined in Console when use <script> tag in custom view page using AdminTabStripEvent

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, nopcommerce

I am using nopCommerce 3.40

I have open custom tab and content from plugin on customer edit page using AdminTabStripCreated Event .

When i am use  tag in custom tab content then i am getting error "i is undefined" jqueryvalidatemin.js in console

my code look like in AdminTabStripCreated

```
   int customerId = Convert.ToInt32(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"]);
                    string url = "/Controller/ActionName?ID=" + customerId;

                    var sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.Append("<style type=\"text/css\">");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(".k-link {font-weight: bold;}");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("</style>");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("<script  type=\"text/javascript\">");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("$(document).ready(function () {");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("var kTabs = $('#customer-edit').data('kendoTabStrip');");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append(" kTabs.append({ text: \"" + tabName + "\", contentUrl: \"" + url + "\" });");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("});");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    sb.Append("</script>");
                    sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
                    eventMessage.BlocksToRender.Add(MvcHtmlString.Create(sb.ToString()));
```

view page content look like:

```
@using Nop.Core.Infrastructure;
@using Nop.Web.Framework;
@using Nop.Web.Framework.UI;
@using System.Web;

<script type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formid" }))
{
 //some code
}
```

please give me suggestion how to handle this error

Comment: why you giving me minus point?